# Share point - usage data/reporting

Tags: sharepoint

I do reporting/analytics for site usage and engagement for a share point online site with my company. I currently run the usage logs manually from site audit reports and the process is very time consuming and not always accurate. Does anyone know a better way to get these logs? Also has anyone had success in implementing a 3rd party platform to capture site visits like google analytics? We have tried to implement Matomo, but not much success.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Please, share what you already tried.

Comment: See [sharepoint.se]

Answer (score 0):

@B1landry,

You may have a try Azure app insight, provides similar functionality to Google Analytics with the advantage of keeping your data in the same ecosystem.

Check below docs to get started:

- https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2019/02/19/how-to-add-application-insights-to-sharepoint-without-modifying-the-master-page/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sharepoint
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/246834/how-can-i-setup-a-sharepoint-online-site-usage-mon-1.html

BR